# how can i reload a particular page which is loaded using jquery .load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I am loading a page in div container using jquery .load() like the example below:

```
jQuery("#ShowOrders").load("saveOrder.php?totalAmount=100" );
```

Inside this page i'm going to handle list of values.

For those list of values i'm going to perform the delete operation like below inside js function,

```
function removeOrder(sId)
{
var ServiceId = parseInt(sId);
var OrderId = parseInt("<?php echo $_POST['OrderId']; ?>");
alert("ServiceId "+ServiceId+" SessionOrderId "+OrderId);
if(confirm("Are you sure?") == true)
{
  var DeleteIt = "<?php include 'connect.php'; $DeleteOrderDetailsQuery = 'DELETE FROM tblshoppingdetails WHERE orderID = "+OrderId+" AND serviceTypeID = "+ServiceId+"';$ExeDeleteOrdersQuery = mysqli_query($con,$DeleteOrderDetailsQuery);if($ExeDeleteOrdersQuery) { echo '1'; } else { echo $DeleteOrderDetailsQuery; } ?>";
}
alert(DeleteIt);
if(DeleteIt == 1)
{
  alert("Success");
}
}
```

I can't able to delete the record in the database and even if i can able to delete this i'm having a bigger problem to reload this particular div to show updates.

I need help in

1. working with sql inside js
2. reloading a page which loaded using jquery .load() function.
3. Can i able to handle ajax in it? (If yes, please suggest me a method to do it.)

Comment: first thing you can use `ajax` instead of `jQuery.Load` function. Where you can easily implement `reload` function after `ajax success` OR `ajax complete`

Comment: @sunil if i implement that can i can add that  delete functionality too within this loaded page

Comment: do you mean you want to run more `ajax` for delete any record ?

Comment: yes ajax inside this ajax loaded page

Comment: Yes you can implementation this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run sql inside js. Assuming you have a script file for saveOrder.php and removeOrder.php file. these files should contain your sql queries and logic that returns the results as an html string. Below is an example of how you might structure your javascript and handle your ajax requests:

```
$(function() {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: 'saveOrder.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html', // data type you are expecting to be returned
        // data you are passing into your saveOrder.php script that runs your sql
        // queries and other logic and returns the result as html
        data: {
            totalAmount: 100
        }
    });

    // on ajax success
    jqxhr.done(function(html){
        console.log("success. order has been saved");
        // assuming saveOrder.php returns html
        // append your list here
        $("#someDiv").empty();
        $("#someDiv").append(html);

        // assuming your list contains a delete button with
        // a data attribute of data-id and where data-id value is the id
        // sql record id you can do the following

        $(".list-item").each(function(index, el) {
            var deleteBtn = $(el).find("#delete");

                deleteBtn.on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // id of the record being deleted
                    // capatured from:
                    // <button data-id="25">Delete</button>
                   var id = $(this).data(id);

                    // here you can run another ajax call
                    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                        url: 'removeOrder.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: {
                            id: id
                        }
                    });

                    // second ajax successful
                    jqxhr.done(function(html){
                        console.log("order removed");

                        // append the updated list
                        $("#someDiv").empty();
                        $("#someDiv").append(html);

                    });

                    jqxhr.fail(function(){
                        console.log("Second Ajax Failed");
                    });
                });

        });

    });

    jqxhr.fail(function(){
        console.log("First Ajax Failed");
    });

});
```